# save CountDown in android studio

Tags: android, countdown

My app has a text view and a button, when I touch the button, the CountDown start but when I close the the app and open again the CountDown return to 0 again. How can I save the CountDown? Is it with shared preferences?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu
        // this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void a(View view){
        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tv1.setText("La cuenta llega a 0 en: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                tv1.setText("Listo!");
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes definitely. SharedPreferences is the right solution for you. When you close the app (`onDestroy`) you persist the value through the `SharedPreferences.Editor` object whereas when the app starts (`onCreate`) you load it.

Examples here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for doing your task :-
1) Saving variable value with sharedpreference :- It is best ways if you want to save only some values saying one or two variables, you can use these source code for it ,
code with shared preference :

```
//To save
SharedPreferences countd = getSharedPreferences("Countdown_NAME", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("SNOW_DENSITY",mSnowDensity);
editor.commit();

//To retrieve
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Countdown_NAME", 0);
int snowDensity = settings.getInt("SNOW_DENSITY", 0);
```

2) Second option is to use sqlite database for these :
In these option you have to code like these:

```
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("your database name",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

Now for Saving count in db you must use these

```
///for saving
mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Counter(counter int);");
mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO TutorialsPoint VALUES(counter);");

///for retriving

Cursor resultSet = mydatbase.rawQuery("Select * from Counter",null);
resultSet.moveToFirst();
String username = resultSet.getInt(1);
```

I hope it will help

Comment: Although for what op is wanting, a db is massively over kill. Shared Preferences is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Hi, sorry i don't explain myself well, what i need is save the count down, when i close and open the app i want that the countdown still continue running